# How to recognize specific regions from image using Tess4j java

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am working on Tess4j for reading passport. Is there any function to recognise only part of passport image such as Name, Surname etc. Does Tesseract supports zonal OCR? How can I achieve this task using Tesseract? Give me some suggestions on it.

Answer (score 2):

We can provide a Rectangle object to Tesseract for performing OCR in specific region.
`Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();`

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(coordinates.getX(), coordinates.getY(), coordinates.getWidth(), coordinates.getHeight());
String result = instance.doOCR(bufferedImage, rect);
```

The result will give us the characters recognized from rectangle region

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the help, But coordinates will not work for all the images. Is there any other way to perform this task.